# Export to CSV using bulk copies data, can't write to local

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

Table in my db should be exported to csv file via bcp query.
I managed to export it on the Server side drive, and it is just fine, **but I can't export to local machine.**

I shared drive, granted full control to everyone.
When I remotely run the server I am not able to ping my machine as request always times out, on the other side, server is accessible from my machine.

I tried to access shared folder on my colleagues computer.
Now I can access his shared folder but the error I am receiving when trying to execute my procedure persisted and writing to server remains the only option.

Here is what I've done...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try a FQDN in the path.

Comment: I had this issue too. Have the network admin create a share to that folder and assign the appropriate permissions. Hide it if you want to. Make `\\SOMETHING-F352B\Bank` a network share. Name it `F352BANK$`. Then  you should be able to bcp to it. `\\F352BANK$\ClientsProba.csv`. If that still doesn't work. Save it locally on the SQL Server as you already did and email it to whomever needs it.

Comment: Tried this, same problem.

Comment: Why do you make it so complicated? Why bcp should be launched from server and not from your client computer?

Answer (score 0):

I think running PowerShell on your local machine might help you out here. And should be fairly straightforward.

> When running the following command ensure you're running PowerShell as an [Administrator](https://www.top-password.com/blog/5-ways-to-run-powershell-as-administrator-in-windows-10/).

```
$server = "**YOUR_SERVER_NAME_WITHOUT_STARS**"
$dbname = "**YOUR_DB_NAME_WITHOUT_STARS**"
$AttachmentPath = "c:\\export.csv"
$QueryFmt= @"
**YOUR_QUERY_WITHOUT_STARS**
"@

Invoke-Sqlcmd   -ServerInstance $server -Database $dbname -Query $QueryFmt | Export-CSV $AttachmentPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I don't doubt this will work but I need it query-like.